# OData vNext ASP.NET 5 - How is this done, has it been released?

Tags: asp.net, odata, asp.net-core

Is there support for OData in ASP.NET vNext/ASP.NET Core 1.0?

If so how do we create our controllers?

Can we get an update for this in April 2016?

Comment: You're asking the wrong persons. This is a Q/A from users for users and while some of the people who answer questions do work for microsoft, you better ask that on the appropriate github repository issue tracker. SO is not for official statements

Comment: I've answered and redirected you to the best way to vote for the feature in an answer below. If it helps, don't hesitate to validate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for OData in ASP.NET Core 1 yet.
Please use the following GitHub issue to help the team prioritize this library: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/741